# PHP Error: Unable to load dynamic library php_intl.dll, not a valid win32 application?

Tags: php, apache, winapi, dll, xampp

I installed `WAMPP` web server, and now after configuring `php.ini` to use *Netbeans* for `PHP` coding (following this), I had to restart the `Apache` and `MySQL` servers. I actually stopped them and tried to start again, and I am getting this error:

**PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:xampp\php\ext\php_intl.dll' - %1 is not a valid Wind32 application.**

I am on a `64 bit Windows 7 OS`.

I installed `XAMPP v1.8.3` (got from *www.apachefriends.org*)

My `PHP` version (got from `phpinfo()` is `PHP version 5.5.11`.

I have tried solutions to the questions addressing the same issue.

[1.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17976764/why-cant-php-on-windows-see-extension-php-intl-dll-even-though-it-exists) I tried to copy all the `icu*.dll`'s to apache>bin directory, no joy. They were already there. I did not replace them.

[2.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451468/intl-extension-installing-php-intl-dll) I have my `extension=php_intl.dll` uncommented and points to the right directory. To no gain.

[3.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451468/intl-extension-installing-php-intl-dll) I added the directory of `icu*.dll` files to my system environment variables, did not help.

[4.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19883527/1-is-not-a-valid-win32-application-for-php-mysql-dll) My `php_pdo_firebird.dll` in `php.ini` is already commented out.

**Now, not a valid win32 application makes me think I have something for 64bit OS and it should be for 32bit OS.. But what is it? What do I do about it?**

**Please help me resolve this error.**

Comment: HAVE You Installed Wampp or Xampp ?

Comment: Was using WAMPP. I was getting the error but I reinstalled everything and I don't get the error anymore,

Comment: ok fine generally wampp comes in two packages wamp x32 bit and x64 bit so you need to install appropriate wampp by checking your machine is whether 32 bit or 64 bit

Answer (score 3):

You have to install **Miscrosoft Visual C++ Redistributable**.
Use x86 version if you use 32bit PHP.
Use x64 version if you use 64bit PHP.

If you are not sure which PHP you use, install both versions of Miscrosoft Visual C++ Redistributable. Nothing will break.

**For PHP 7.2, PHP 7.3 and PHP 7.4** you need **version 2017** (VC15).

[Download Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2017](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads)
Older versions (2015 or 2012) are not needed if you install this one.

**For PHP 7.0 and PHP 7.1** you need **version 2015** (VC14).

[Download Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145).

**For PHP 5.6** you need **version 2012** (VC11).

[Download Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2012](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679)

Answer (score 0):

1. Change/Add env variable for PATH to your php version
2. Download Visual C++ will resolve